# Windows Forms вывод графика

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

Есть функция

```
 GraphPane pane = new GraphPane();
        ZedGraphControl zgc = new ZedGraphControl();
        zgc.GraphPane = pane;



        pane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Координата X";//подпись оси X
        pane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Координата Y";//подпись оси Y
        pane.Title.Text = "График функции y=x^2";//подпись графика

        pane.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.LightSkyBlue, 45.0f);
        pane.Chart.Fill.Type = FillType.None;
        pane.Legend.Position = LegendPos.Float;
        pane.Legend.IsHStack = false;





        //pane.CurveList.Clear();

        LineItem curve = pane.AddCurve(name,time,points,color);
        pane.AxisChange();

        curve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.White);
        zgc.AxisChange();
        zgc.Refresh();
        zgc.Visible = true;
```

Как сделать так, чтоб график строился в определенном Panel.
Которую я создал в конструкторе форм.
Спасибо !

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте созданный `zgc` внутрь панели:

```
panel.Controls.Add(zgc);
```

По желанию можете растянуть график на всю панель:

```
zgc.Dock = Dock.Fill;
```

Comment: Спасибо, а еще вопрос там курсор появляется и если там проводить то график увеличивается и потом вообще исчезает, можно ли как то это камеру настроить, надеюсь понятно))

Comment: @user207044 непонятно.